# Firefox renders HTML before applying CSS

Tags: html, css, flask

I'm running a simple Flask server on Ubuntu, basically a beginner with web apps. When I request a page through Firefox, the screen flashes briefly with the raw HTML before the CSS is applied.

I thought this was a problem with the way the CSS is specified in the HTML (as I found in a few suggestions) but it doesn't seem to be the case because my other browser Brave doesn't have this problem, not even when the CSS resource is requested for the very first time or if I disable caching from the Network tab and refresh repeatedly. It always loads correctly without any flashing or flickering (to my eyes anyways). Below is the current HTML head.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Flask Auth Example</title>
    <!-- <div id="loadOverlay" style="background-color:#333; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width:100%; height:100%; z-index:2000;"></div> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/styles/bulma.min.css" />
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.min.css" /> -->
</head>
```

Has anyone experienced this issue and is it browser specific? What is the simplest way to resolve it?

Comment: I think you'll have to provide more information on what you're doing if you want help with this. What's the snippet we included? Is it part of a template that you're trying to render?

Comment: @Till I can't include all the HTML files, this is the base template with which all the pages get rendered. What follows is just the simple body. You'll have to be more specific if you need more info.

Comment: In your base template are you not using `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='file.css') }}">` with your static folder correctly defined or is this source copied from your browser directly?

Comment: @Till No, this is from the actual base template file on disk. The CSS (relative) path is hard-coded for now since it's just one file. The Flask server serves it up without my app's interference. I'll try your suggestion but I don't think it's much different from the present.

Comment: Yep, just checked, still the same. It's looking browser-specific so far, though I've only tried it on two.

Comment: For what it’s worth I’m having a similar problem which only started recently so I suspect there’s a bug in Firefox. Might be worth checking bugzilla.